# Convert Visual Studio project to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, project

I have a visual studio project which is an ASP.NET MVC project, however it doesn't recognize it as such in Visual Studio so I don't get the nice dropdowns with Add View and such. Rather I just get a very plain add file dialog which doesn't include any MVC file templates. When I create a new MVC project however I get all the nice little VS tools. So, can someone tell me how I can instruct VS to recognize the project as an MVC project?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, to answer my own question, you have to change the projecttypeguids in the project file. In the case of ASP.NET MVC RC1 they are:

{603c0e0b-db56-11dc-be95-000d561079b0};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}

Though of course these may vary depending on the version you're targeting.

Answer (score 7):

For ASP.Net MVC 3, you will have to change the ProjectTypeGuids property in the project file to:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```